# Multilevel data storage

Tags: matlab

This is an example of how my code is working:

```
x=ones(1,10)
y=zero(1,15)
Z{1,1}=x
Z{1,2}=y
```

Now I need an extra level of storage. I'm looking for something similar to a vector of Z's (Z(1),Z(2),Z(3),etc.).
Would this be possible? Thanks.

Comment: An extra level, like `Z{1,3}`? Else you can always have `Z2{1}=Z;` it just looks a bit obfuscated (and perhaps a bad solution)

Comment: You can have a parent cell array: parent_z = {Z1, Z2, ....}

Comment: You've already got an unused dimension in your example. If you're trying to get more `x` and `y` arrays, you can use `Z{2,1}=x2; Z{2,2}=y2;`. If you're already using those in your real data, you can add another dimension like `Z{2,1,2}`. I'm not sure I fully understand what end result you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do that can't already be accomplished with the approach you have now.